# Huggingface Seq2seqTrainer freezes on evaluation

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, openai-whisper, huggingface-trainer

I'm currently trying to train a Whisper model by following the [Fine Tune Whisper Model](https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper#training-and-evaluation) tutorial. However, during the training phase where I call `trainer.train()`. I see the progress bar progresses through the training, but when it reaches the evaluation step defined at the training arguments, it will just freeze and the progress bar just stalls up. No error output, no nothing. And it will look like this.

[image]

I'm using Kaggle notebooks to write the code with GPU P100 turned on. Here are my training arguments leading up to the training function.

```py
from transformers import WhisperForConditionalGeneration

model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small")

model.config.forced_decoder_ids = None
model.config.suppress_tokens = []
model.generation_config.language = "en"
```

```py
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./whisper-small-eng-gen",  # change to a repo name of your choice
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,  # increase by 2x for every 2x decrease in batch size
    learning_rate=1e-5,
    warmup_steps=500,
    max_steps=1000,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    fp16=True,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    generation_max_length=225,
    save_steps=1000,
    eval_steps=1000,
    logging_steps=25,
    report_to=["tensorboard"],
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="wer",
    greater_is_better=False,
    push_to_hub=True,
    ignore_data_skip=True
)
```

```py
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    args=training_args,
    model=model,
    train_dataset=common_voice_train,
    eval_dataset=common_voice_test,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor,
)
```

> Initially, the `max_steps` for training is 4000, and it always stalls at step 1001.

I think it is also worth noting that my dataset is streamed, and it is an Iterable Dataset.

Any help is appreciated!

****Update****
I edited my code to include verbose logging with

```py
import transformers

transformers.logging.set_verbosity_info()
```

And this is the log after the evaluation step is reached.

> You have passed language=en, but also have set `forced_decoder_ids` to [[1, None], [2, 50359]] which creates a conflict. `forced_decoder_ids` will be ignored in favor of language=en.

Comment: I believe there is a parameter `do_eval=True`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @rocket_boomerang_19 the parameter for training arguments? I added it and tested it again, still the same result.